# If a k-regular graph of even order remains connected when any k-2 edges are deleted, it has a 1-factor

Tags: graph-theory

Im learning graph theory on my own and recently got the book Introduction to Graph Theory by West. It contains the following problem that I am quite stuck on.

Let G be a k-regular graph of even order that remains connected when any k-2 edges are deleted. Prove that G has a 1-factor (perfect matching).

I havent gotten anywhere with anything but Im sorta thinking contradiction? Pointers would be appreciated, doesnt have to be a full proof thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're asking about is Exercise 3.3.16 on p. 147 of the second edition of West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*. The "even order" assumption is of course redundant when $k$ is odd. The proposition is trivial if $k=1$ ($G=K_2$) or $k=2$ ($G$ is an even cycle). The case $k=3$ does not seem trivial. Leafing through the preceding pages of text, I found the case $k=3$ stated and proved as Corollary 3.3.8 on p. 139. If I had to work this exercise, the first thing I'd do is study that proof carefully. Then I try to generalize it, first for $k=4$, then for general $k$. Also, hoping it's not too much of a spoiler, I might look for a hint in Appendix C: Hints for Selected Exercises. The hint for this one is on p. 511, and it just says "Generalize the argument of Corollary 3.3.8."

But maybe you've already read that hint, and you need help in figuring out how to generalize the proof of 3.3.8? In that's where you're stuck, you should have said so.

Comment: Wow i hadnt seen that appendix of hints, that will be super helpful for my studying. I will try this and get back to you if Im still stuck. Thank you!