# $k$-regular even graph, still connected after removing k-2 edges has a 1$-factor

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I have been asked to show that for a $k$-regular graph with even number of vertices has a $1$-factor if the graph stays connected after $k-2$ edges have been removed.
I do not know how to start this, but I think I could use Tutte's theorem somehow but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any hint or know how to solve it?

I have seen similar posts before but they have never had a complete answer, only hints.

Previous posts:

[If a k-regular graph of even order remains connected when any k-2 edges are deleted, it has a 1-factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534194/if-a-k-regular-graph-of-even-order-remains-connected-when-any-k-2-edges-are-dele)

[Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph, with $|V(G)|$ even, that remains connected when any $k − 2$ edges are deleted. Prove that $G$ has a $1$-factor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121833/let-g-be-a-k-regular-graph-with-vg-even-that-remains-connected-when)

Comment: Did you try to follow the hints, especially those in the second answer? I know reading and understanding proofs is nice, but finding them for oneself (even when given hints) is way more fun. It is even beneficial in that years later you still will recall that one hack you needed to solve an exercise, which was bugging you for two weeks straight...

Comment: PrudiiArca, yeah I tried but I cannot wrap my head around the idea Misha Lavrov gives in that answer. I understand the ideas he share but not how to boil everything down and actually get something out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma.** In a $k$-regular graph $G$, if $S \subseteq V(G)$ with $|S|$ odd, there cannot be exactly $k-1$ edges between $S$ and $V(G)-S$.

**Proof.** Suppose there are $k-1$ such edges. Then $\sum_{v \in S}\deg(s) = k|S|$ counts each edge between two vertices in $S$ twice, and each edge from $S$ to $V(G)-S$ once, so there are $\frac{k|S|-(k-1)}{2}$ edges between two vertices in $S$. But this simplifies to $k \cdot \frac{|S|-1}{2} + \frac12$, which is not an integer. $\square$

---

Now we are ready to apply Tutte's theorem. Let $U$ be any nonempty subset of $V(G)$. Then there are at most $k|U|$ edges out of $U$. If $C$ is an odd component of $G-U$, it must receive at least $k$ of those edges: there cannot be $k-2$ or fewer by the connectivity condition, and there cannot be $k-1$ by the lemma. Therefore there can be at most $\frac{k|U|}{k}$ odd components.

If $U = \varnothing$, then the connectivity condition does not apply, because there might just be one odd component $C$ which is the whole graph. This is where we need the assumption that $|V(G)|$ is even.

Comment: Thank you, it was the upper limit of the odd components that I could not find. But I understand it now!